# How to delete keys in ZODB storage?

Tags: python, zodb

I've started working with ZODB in my Python project. It's nice, but how to remove certain entries from storage?

I've tried this:

```
storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('stats.fs')
db = DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
root['key1'] = 'test
root.remove('key1')
```

But I'm getting error 
`AttributeError: 'PersistentMapping' object has no attribute 'remove'`

How to remove an entry?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, that was pretty easy though not very obvious (at least, for me):
`del root['key1']`

Strangely, there's no info about this in ZODB documentation.

Comment: It is a [*mapping* type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), it behaves just like a dictionary. Loads of Python libraries follow that pattern, so to repeat the documentation of how a Python mapping behaves would be.. redundant.